# Google Tag Manager trigger not firing with specific conditions

Tags: google-analytics, triggers, google-tag-manager

I have Google Tag Manager setup for a client of ours. We are trying to track a simple mailto link on the website. The link tag wraps an image icon like so:

```
<a class="email-share-link" title="share-email" href="mailto:someone@example.com"><img src="icon.gif" /></a>
```

We are able to send the title attribute to Google via the Tag configuration, but ONLY when the Trigger is setup to fire on ALL clicks. We only want this data sent to Google when this particular link is clicked. We attempted at configuring the trigger to fire when the title tag contains "share-email" but the trigger is not firing. When we change trigger to fire on "All Clicks" we see the title attribute in Google Analytics. Here is the setup we have attempted:

**Tag Configuration:**

Track Type: Event
Label: {{Link Title Attribute}}
Non-Interaction Hit: False

**Trigger Configuration:**

Trigger Type: Click - All Elements
This Trigger Fires On: Some Clicks
Fire this Trigger When Event Occurs: Link Title Attribute contains share-email

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is your `{{Link Title Attribute}}` configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use the CSS class `email-share-link` in your trigger (assuming that that class is specific only to the mailto link).

Alternate tagging solution: I tried this configuration and it seems to be working, as in when I click the image, the gtm.linkClick event fires the tag with the label containing "share-email"

**Tag**

[image: Tag]

**Trigger**

[image]

**Link Title Attribute variable**

[image]

Comment: Wondering why you needed to add Link Title Attribute value when this is already a built in variable in GTM.

Comment: It's not exactly built-in, but can be acquired easily with an auto-event type variable. Were you thinking of something else?